# iframe loads relative url as http even though the parent url was loaded with https

Tags: iframe, https, mixed-content

I am getting this error in the browser console:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://async-java.github.io' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure resource 'http://async-java.github.io/v/0.1.2/'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

my iframe is being loaded with:

```
<iframe id="main-iframe" src="v/0.1.2" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

is there some way to force it to use https without having to use an absolute URL? The relative url is a lot more convenient because it works for localhost etc.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors on my end using both Safari and Firefox w/ HTTPS Everywhere. Could something in your browser be set up incorrectly?

Comment: Same error even with `src="https://async-java.github.io/v/0.1.2/"` in Chrome, bizarre (and it's not a redirect, either)

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, and it turns out that something can be done in nginx, like `add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this answer, it says to use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

which worked for this use case. For more info see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

Comment: I had the same problem with Google Chrome 98. Although the page was retrieved with https and the IFRAME tag's src had no protocol part (/....), the browser was trying to retrieve the iframe content over http (I was using an invalid ssl certificate). This meta tag resolved it. Thx.